# How to install JRE in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, java

I tried installing [JRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Virtual_Machine#Execution_environment) on Ubuntu, but when I go online and check the site it still says that the latest JRE is not installed.

Is there shortest automatic way to install JRE in Ubuntu so that it works with Firefox?

The other thing is, which directory should I install it in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UbuntuGeek: [How to Install Java Runtime Environment (JRE) in Ubuntu 9.04 (Jaunty)](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-install-java-runtime-environment-jre-in-ubuntu-904-jaunty.html)

Comment: I tried that but stll site says that JRE is not installed

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you shouldn't be worrying about to which directory JRE is going to be 
installed, this is something that a package manager tool (like apt-get) will take care of.

To install Java and verify results, follow these steps:

a) Open terminal

b) Use apt-get to install required packages by typing:

> `sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre sun-java6-plugin sun-java6-fonts`

c) To verify that Java has really installed, try typing:

> `java -version`

d) If this is OK, then try testing if the Firefox plugin is installed and running, by typing the following URL to the address bar:

> `about:plugins`

You should find references to Java there.

When you've figure out which step did not work, it is much easier to troubleshoot!